# Win 10 IoT TPM on Raspberry pi c#

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, tpm

I'm on the final bits of my app, and I came across with TPM (Trusted Platform Module). 
Looks very promising for storing tokens and URLS.

I'm trying to make it work with Raspberry pi 3 and c#.

After doing all the config and code, when trying to deploy the app I've got this error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       DEP6956 : Failed to establish connection to the device due to protocol incompatibility. Please try again, and if this error persists, please try restarting the target device. Device supports protocol 'Sirep2'.

looks like I'm not able to connect any more.

I have two questions:
1) Is possible to use TPM and Raspberry pi 3?
2) Would you recommend TPM to store Tokens and URLs? Is there another secure way of doing it?

Thank you all

Comment: What module you are using now? Brand, model.

Comment: I'm using Raspberry pi 3 B.

Comment: The question was about model of TPM.

Comment: I found out that raspberry 3 doesn't support TPM, and I have to install an additional app to support it, to emulate it. Have you ever try this? Where are you storing your tokens?

Comment: I am not sure whether we are talking about the same. But TPM is hardware module (chip or board). Raspberry does not have such module and you have to add it with external board.

Comment: Perfect, Tanks for your help I'll try another way to store data securely on the raspberry.

Comment: You can save the data on SD card in encrypted form. If the password is entered by user at runtime, it is safe enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is possible to use TPM and Raspberry pi 3?

Yes, with IoT Core Dashboard you can [install a software-emulated TPM](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/20/building-secure-apps-for-windows-iot-core/#qcZ7kMuX2W9b0R2G.97) on Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 which don’t have a TPM chip.

> 2) Would you recommend TPM to store Tokens and URLs?

Having the secure information stored in the TPM can help [protect them from disclosure](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/tpm). From this point of view, I recommend using TPM.

Comment: Hi Rita, thank you for your answer, do you know any "Software-emulated TPM" I could use, I've been browsing around, not much luck in finding a suitable one.

Comment: @JuanPiaggio [IoT Core Dashboard](https://iottools.blob.core.windows.net/iotdashboard/setup.exe) will help you to install a software-emulated TPM and you don't need to find any **"Software-emulated TPM"**. What you need to do is just follow [this tutorial](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/20/building-secure-apps-for-windows-iot-core/#btPCULFuPdP7L9Xd.97).

Comment: Hi Rita, do you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868354/using-tpm-on-raspberry-pi-error-when-compiling-to-native . Looks like when I use the library you mention, and I try to build to native, I get a long list of errors

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your error message is directly related to the TPM. This error usually occurs when an iot-core version or related library has been updated. To solve it, I always clean my project, shutdown all VisualStudio 15 or 17 instances and then restart them and rebuild/deploy. No reboot necessary. This has always worked for me.