# Using Tpm on Raspberry pi - error when compiling to native

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, tpm

I'm using Microsoft.Devices.Tpm, and it's been difficult to debug the issues.

When I add the package Microsoft.Devices.Tpm and trying to compile to native or build the package, I get the following errors:

```
1>  Starting .NET Native compilation
1>  Processing application code
1>...\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(35): warning : ILTransform_0027: Method 'CreateLambda' within 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found.
1>...\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(91): warning : ILTransform_0027: Method 'ParameterIsAssignable' within 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found.
1>  Computing application closure and generating interop code
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'Tbsi_Context_Create!tbs.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'Tbsip_Context_Close!tbs.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'Tbsip_Submit_Command!tbs.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'Tbsip_Cancel_Commands!tbs.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'SetDllDirectory!kernel32.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_TPM_Init!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'TPM_Manufacture!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'ExecuteCommand!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'Signal_Hash_Start!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'Signal_Hash_Data!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'Signal_Hash_End!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__Signal_PhysicalPresenceOn!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__Signal_PhysicalPresenceOff!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__Signal_PowerOn!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__Signal_PowerOff!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__SetCancel!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__ClearCancel!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__NVEnable!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__NVDisable!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__RsaKeyCacheControl!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__LocalitySet!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__SetNvAvail!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_plat__ClearNvAvail!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
1>  Generating serialization code
1>  Compiling interop code
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.AddKnownContractsLists(McgCodeTypeDeclaration container, ContractTables tables)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.GenerateDataContractSerializerHelperCode(IEnumerable`1 contracts, IEnumerable`1 jsonContracts, IEnumerable`1 wcfSerializers)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.GenerateDataContractSerializerHelper(IEnumerable`1 contracts, IEnumerable`1 jsonContracts, GeneratorSettings settings, String intermediateAssembly, IEnumerable`1 wcfSerializers)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Internal compiler error: One or more errors occurred.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Should I use a different library? 
In Debug mode, works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-hub-vs-cs/issues/9), and Microsoft is working on it.

Stay tuned.

Comment: "MSFT knows about it and is working on a fix. For now, if you can disable compilation with .Net Native, it should work."

Comment: You can get rid of the error and compile by adding an exclusion, but it still won't run, seems like the SDK blocks the APIs : https://github.com/Microsoft/TSS.MSR/issues/8 Why so slow!